# Why slice() is showing error but code run perfectly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have written this code in js (developer.js) file.

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
  return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

now, this code i put because i needed to reverse the ng-repeat result, so I created manual filter.

But this code is working perfectly but its showing error in console.

And i don't want to see my console with all errors.

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://192.168.0.14/test/js/developer.js:35:24)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:69:187)
    at Ia.| (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:129:335)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:68:341
    at Ia.| (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:129:340)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:68:341
    at Object.e.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:88:347)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:147:244)
    at Object.e.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:86:286)
    at Object.e.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:88:506)
```

P.S.

This error will be shown first 4 times when i have total 6 values inside items.

items is having object array.

when I try to console items in filter, its for first 4 times, showing '**undefined**' and then for last two times, its showing,

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

inside that objects, the values are defined

items hold this array of objects [data is coming in json form].

```
{
id: "51c2824088358f0d39000000",
name: "clientdemo",
key: ***,
secret: ***,
description: "It is good.",
icon_url: "/oauth2/static/media/images/icon/default.png"
},
{
id: "51c2cca588358f35aa000003",
name: "grantallllla",
key: ***,
secret: ***,
description: "This asdf",
icon_url: "/oauth2/static/media/images/icon/default.png"
},
{
id: "51d14e8c88358f6e96000024",
name: "12341234",
key: ***,
secret: ***,
description: "Enter descript12341234ion here",
icon_url: "/oauth2/static/media/images/icon/default.png"
},
{
id: "51d14e9888358f6e96000026",
name: "sdfgds345",
key: ***,
secret: ***,
description: "dsfasdfasdfasdf",
icon_url: "/oauth2/static/media/images/icon/default.png"
},
{
id: "51d1758888358f5171000002",
name: "1321",
key: ***,
secret: ***,
description: "zxcvzxcvcxvbxcvb",
icon_url: "/oauth2/static/media/images/icon/51c2819e88358f0d2a000000_1372701408_RhLW.jpg"
},
{
id: "51d3d8c588358f461a000002",
name: "sdafasdf",
key: ***,
secret: ***,
description: "asdfasdf",
icon_url: "/oauth2/static/media/images/icon/51c2819e88358f0d2a000000_1372857885_PSzB.jpg"
}
```

Comment: so apparently the first 4 entries of your items array are undefined...

Comment: Can you dump your `items` ?

Comment: 1. The items that you are passing to the service - are they fetched using `$http` initially? 2. Can you write the code that calls the service? As in, is this present in the controller, if so how is it called (and when is it called)? - To me it looks like when the service is called, the item may not have been populated - Why don't you add a simple if condition inside your service - `if (angular.isArray(items)) {//Proceed to splice}` - It should solve your problem...

Comment: @Christoph I think OP means that when the service is called for the first 4 times, he gets that error. That should not imply that the first four elements are undefined - it is just that when the service was called first four times, it had no array to splice.

Comment: @callmekatootie that wasn't obvious from the first version of his question. Also it does not matter. The array entries are undefined and thus throw that error. So a proper error handling is needed to catch this and/or investigation why the first calls do not return proper data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried handling the actual error?

Maybe just try this?

```
app.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    if( !items ){ return; } // This will take care of the error
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

You may also want to know why some of your data is undefined, there may be an issue you may have to deal with.